# Ошибки перевода в профиле пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

Очевидные ошибки в локализации профиля пользователя:

- посещение - последний (должно быть "последнее")
- 101 репутации - не хватает слова, к примеру, "балл"
- вкладка "уважение", должно быть "репутация"?
- в истории репутации, "править" как индикатор совершенного действия, должно быть "правка".
- "all actions" - не переведено
- "1 days, 1 consecutive" - не переведено

Comment: Пожалуйста, пробегайтесь перед отправкой по вопросам с меткой [meta-tag:Локализация], чтобы избегать повторных багрепортов.

Comment: Не нашел ни одной из представленных ошибок. Если что-то пропустил, пожалуйста, дайте знать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "править" все-еще в профиле, как и было. Зайдите в мой профиль, посмотрите активность на вкладке репутация за 7 апреля 2015.